# C# UserControl delegate and events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I have little problem with an event in a Windows Forms application. I can't get access to UserControl Event in `Form1`.

```
public partial class KomisControl : UserControl
{

    public KomisControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private static KomisControl _instance;

    public static KomisControl Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new KomisControl();
            return _instance;
        }

    }
    public delegate void AddButtonEventHandler(object o, EventArgs e);

    public event AddButtonEventHandler AddButtonEv;

    protected virtual void OnAddButton()
    {
        AddButtonEv?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnAddButton();

    }
}
```

Form1:

[image: Form1]

Comment: You're trying to type your code outside of the method

Comment: please don't post code as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the event is not `static` so it will no be accessible with only the class name. You need to use the `Instance` variable and you need write the code inside the scope of the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    //..all the other stuff.....
    KomisControl.Instance.AddButtonEv += ...

}
```

Comment: The calling code is also not being made within a method, it's just floating in space

Comment: @LordWilmore thanks, I just noticed and added it into the answer